Application crashes with SIGABRT after Docker start up in thread creation
I am encountering a very strange situation.
I have an application which starts when my container starts using systemd.
When the Docker container starts, this application crashes with a SIGABRT with the following:
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: [[0;1;31mfailed[[0m (Result: signal) since Mon 2024-12-16 16:45:10 UTC+9; 8s ago
Process: 115 ExecStart=/home/myapp [[0;1;31m(code=killed, signal=ABRT)[[0m
Main PID: 115 (code=killed, signal=ABRT)

Jan 10 15:13:31 9dc3c3a57bac myapp[70]:     #1 0x7f2d2640e9dc in __gthread_create /usr/src/debug/gcc-runtime/9.5.0-r0/x86_64-common-linux/libstdc++-v3/include/x86_64-common-linux/bits/gthr-default.h:663
Jan 10 15:13:31 9dc3c3a57bac myapp[70]:     #2 0x7f2d2640e9dc in std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) ../../../../../../../../../work-shared/gcc-9.5.0-r0/gcc-
9.5.0/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/thread.cc:135
Jan 10 15:13:31 9dc3c3a57bac myapp[70]:     #3 0x55d908be7f07 in std::thread::thread<void (Service::*)(), Service*, void>(void (Service::*&&)(), Service*&&) /sysroots/core2-64-common-linux/usr/include/c++/9.5.0/thread:130

However, if I restart the same application via systemd, it works without any issue.
It looks like the first start after the  Docker instance starts is somehow problematic.
I cannot share the exact source code, but basically it seems that this application fails during the creation of a thread, a little bit like below:
class ServiceConnector{
    private:
        std::thread reception_thread;
    public:
        ~ServiceConnector(){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
            if(reception_thread.joinable()){
                reception_thread.join();
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        }

        void SocketReceptionMethod(void)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << "[ServiceConnector] waiting message ...\n";
            /* more stuff here like opening a socket, etc. */
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << "[ServiceConnector] OK message!\n";
        }
        void Start()
        {
            // the following seems to be the problematic instruction but only in the described conditions
            //  |    |    |
            //  v    v    v
            reception_thread = std::thread(std::bind(&ServiceConnector::SocketReceptionMethod,this));
        }
};

int main() {
    ServiceConnector connector;
    connector.Start();
}

I was expecting that this application would run identically whether it is at the start up of the Docker container or during.
When I comment the instantiation of the thread, that same application runs correctly at startup, but I am now missing some of its features.
Thanks in advance for the help!

SIGABRT can be a result of exception leaving main(). std::thread's constructor can throw if OS (in this case embedded within Docker) returns an error, so if you cannot attach debugger to your program in Docker then I'd try a try/catch in main to at least print the exception (if this is the root cause).

Using systemd in a container can lead to a bunch of problems, since systemd tries to manage a lot of system-level things that the host system and Docker itself also try to manage.  Do you have the same issue if you take systemd out of the picture and run your same binary as the main container CMD?

Have you tried using a debugger?

Unrelated: std::thread(std::bind(&ServiceConnector::SocketReceptionMethod,this)) No need to do this. You can just do std::thread(&ServiceConnector::SocketReceptionMethod,this)

Thank you @Botje, I will update my code.
Thank you @/JesperJuhl , that's a very good point. I used gdb but only after the Docker container has started and this is too late because that application is supposed to be launched at startup.
When I used gdb after the application has crashed once, that application runs fine and there is nothing valuable to check via gdb.
I launched the app at startup with strace and collected the output, but I didn't saw something strange or anything.
Thank you @/Yksisarvinen, let me try this.
Thank you @/DavidMaze,I will also try your suggestion.
